# How can I download the entire contents of a directory using wget, but excluding files with a particular suffix with the use of a wildcard?

Tags: wget

I have a locally-hosted server, and am attempting to download all files to my remote Ubuntu-based machine via wget. I need to download all files from my HTTP server in a single directory, ensuring that everything apart from files with a suffix of "_test" is obtained - so in other words, I need to make sure that any file with that suffix isn't grabbed. I've tried the following command:

```
wget -r http://my-server-ip/data -R '*_test'
```

The above command results in wget fetching everything from the server - including files with the "`_test`" suffix. I realise that multiple examples of how to use this command correctly exist, but none appear to suit my use case. I should also note that I'm using the bash shell.

Comment: Do you have local files that match `*_test`? In this case the shell would replace `*_test` with the list of matching files. You should quote the pattern: `wget -r http://my-server-ip/data -R "*_test"`, see https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Recursive-Accept_002fReject-Options.html

Comment: @Bodo - Thank you for the suggestion. I don't have any local files with this suffix - when testing by adding quotation marks around the wildcard, this unfortunately still downloads all files (including the ones suffixed with "test").

Comment: Elliott94 per your comment I've added quotes to your command so that others don't sidetrack on that.

Comment: Please move the `-R '*_test'` earlier in the command, per documentation that states `wget [option]... [URL]...`, so it's `wget -r -R '*_test' http://my-server-ip/data` and see if that helps.

Comment: Please copy&paste a few real example file names **to your question**, both wanted and unwanted files.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for your thoughts. In the end, the following command worked for me - this is the case when I have multiple files that I don't wish to grab, all having a suffix of "_test.sh":

```
wget -r http://my-server-ip/ -R "*_test.sh"
```

I also forgot that this particular folder contained files with the same suffix - but several also had an upper-case "T" at the start of "Test" - so, this command ensured that both cases were covered:

```
wget -r http://my-server-ip/ -R "*_test.sh" -R "*_Test.sh"
```

Comment: Can you combine the patterns, using `'*_[Tt]est.sh'`?